# Get 3 counts from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show the following results to the user

> All:8000 enabled:8000 disabled:0

What can I do to improve this code?

```
$Val = explode(",", urldecode($_POST['Val']));
$table = mysqliChkData($Val[0]);

$addSQL = '';
if (!empty($Val[2])) {
  // parrent.guid
  $addSQL.= " and up_cls='".mysqliChkData($Val[2])."'";
}

$getSQL = "Select guid From `".$table."` Where 1=1".$addSQL." GROUP BY guid";
$listData = $sql->Select($getSQL);
$arr['allNum'] = $listData['num'];

$getSQL = "Select guid From `".$table."` Where `chk`='Y'".$addSQL." GROUP BY guid";
$listData = $sql->Select($getSQL);
$arr['openNum'] = $listData['num'];
$arr['closeNum'] = $arr['allNum'] - $arr['openNum'];

echo json_encode($arr); 
exit;
```

Same records but different languages will have same `guid`.

Child tables have `up_cls` column.

Few tables don't have `chk` column because no need to disable.

```
CREATE TABLE tablee (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lang` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `chk` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `guid` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `modify_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-12-31 16:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`guid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

method Select

```
function Select($sql) {
  global $mysqli;
  $reData = array();
  $reData['data'] = array();

  $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
  if ($rs) {
    $thisNum = $rs->num_rows;
  }
  else {
    $thisNum = 0;
  }
  $reData['num'] = $thisNum;
  if ($thisNum != 0) {
    while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
      $reData['data'][] = $row;
    }

  }
  return $reData;
}
```

===============

> Why are you mentioning child tables in this question?

$addSQL.= " and up_cls='".mysqliChkData($Val[2])."'";

> Are you comfortable with scrapping your Select function ...because it is insecure. 
>   Why are you mixing procedural with object-oriented mysqli syntax?

It passed acunetix last year, I don't know it's insecure. Could you give me some advice about this.

> Is there a reason that you cannot query once, then use php to filter the result set based on chk? 
>   How about a conditional count within the SELECT clause?

It is because some tables don't have `chk` . If the query has `chk` it will broken.

Comment: Why are you mentioning child tables in this question? Are you comfortable with scrapping your `Select` function ...because it is insecure.  Why are you mixing procedural with object-oriented mysqli syntax? Why do you pass `$act` to your function if you never use it? Is there a reason that you cannot query once, then use php to filter the result set based on `chk`?  How about a conditional count within the SELECT clause?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple counts from the table based on a condition using a [CASE WHEN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), and when writing SQL or something where formatting helps readability it's normally a good idea to [use heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```php
$getSQL = <<<SQL
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT guid) AS allNum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN chk='Y' THEN guid END) AS openNum
FROM `{$table}`
WHERE
    1=1
    {$addSQL}
SQL;

$listData = $sql->Select($getSQL);
$arr = $listData['data'][0];

$arr['closeNum'] = $arr['allNum'] - $arr['openNum'];

echo json_encode($arr); 
exit;
```

Comment: 1. `$listData['data'][0]`? 2. How does heredoc syntax, in this case, improve readability in a way that double quotes does not? 3. `exit()` can receive `json_encode($arr)` as a parameter to remove the need for `echo`.